# Convert ruby source code from old style to new style hash

Tags: ruby

Anybody knows a converter which takes a list of ruby source files and reliably replaces all old style (hash-rocket) hashes to new style (ruby 1.9) hash syntax? :)

Comment: Out of pure curiosity: Why?

Comment: probably a bad idea to do this -- the only thing you might introduce are errors.

Comment: I think there's a gem for that(tm) which was mentioned on rubyflow a few months ago.

Comment: You could setup a RegEx to go through your source files and try to make the change, but there may be edge cases that aren't picked up. Like the others have mentioned, it's probably not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) is a static code analyzer that evaluates your code against many of the recommendations of the Ruby Style Guide. It has an `--auto-correct` option that can automatically change your code to what is recommended. One of those auto-correct options is for [hash syntax](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/style/hash_syntax.rb).

**Example**:

```
rubocop --only HashSyntax --auto-correct
```

will only correct your hashes.

Comment: if you want to auto-correct all fixes you can simply run a `rubocop` command with `--auto-correct` option.

Answer (score 13):

The gem [hash_syntax](https://github.com/michaeledgar/hash_syntax) is capable of converting from the old style hash to the new style hash, or vice versa.

Once you've installed the gem, you just have to do in the project's root directory

```
hash_syntax --to-19
```

to convert from old to new, or

```
hash_syntax --to-18
```

to convert from new to old.

Comment: `hash_syntax` is old, crashes when run over our codebase and does not modify all things correctly. Use rubocop.

Answer (score 1):

I did with the [hash_syntax](https://github.com/michaeledgar/hash_syntax) gem with following commands:

```
gem install hash_syntax

hash_syntax --to-19 lib/foo.rb
```