# Gem or script to turn old ruby syntax into new syntax (:symbol => "whatever" into symbol: "whatever")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've gotten used to reading the new ruby syntax symbol: "whatever" instead of :symbol => "whatever"

Is there some kind of "turn all of the old syntax into the new syntax" script that I could reliably run on my project? Doing it by hand would take a long time in this project as it is fairly large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19376294/3880374) from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287794/convert-ruby-source-code-from-old-style-to-new-style-hash). Looks like Rubocop's [`--auto-correct` option](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#autocorrect) will take care of this for you.

Example usage:
`rubocop --only HashSyntax --auto-correct`

Comment: This worked pretty well but it looks like it skipped over my view code...it only modified models, controllers, and db...

Comment: @gregblass Turns out Rubocop doesn't support parsing .erb files: https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/issues/1113. But one of the issue commenters recommended the Ruumba gem, which lints .rb and .erb: https://github.com/ericqweinstein/ruumba. Could be worth a shot.